# Mule MEL check for NullPayload vs null

Tags: mule

According to the following ticket: https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-6427 For `NullPayload` I should be able to use :

```
<when expression="#[payload == null]">
```

but that fails. So instead I have to use:

```
<when expression="#[payload is NullPayload]">
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or is this the correct way for checking for `null` or `NullPayload`?

Answer (score 9):

In theory, this *should* be fixed, but it doesn't looks like so. I'm using CE 3.4.0 and the expression `#[payload == null]` doesn't work for `NullPayload`.

I've found [this link](http://www.javaroots.com/2014/12/how-to-check-for-null-payload-in-mule.html) that shows how to check if payload is `NullPayload` correctly:

```
#[payload is org.mule.transport.NullPayload]
```

I actually needed to know if payload was **not** `NullPayload`, so my expression was:

```
#[!(payload is org.mule.transport.NullPayload)]
```

Works like a charm. :)

Comment: Thanks @mathielo, I was going crazy. The [MULE-6427](https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-6427) said it was fixed and even their [MEL expression page](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Expression+Language+Tips) says you should be able to use `#[payload == null]` but only your solution works for me. Many thanks again!

Comment: Thanks, you helped me :) Mulesoft is very poor documented :(

Answer (score 4):

In Mule 3.7, (Studio 5.2) for a `NullPayload`, `#[payload == null]` now returns `true`.  Interestingly, `#[payload is NullPayload]` returns `false`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to check:

`#[payload == empty]`

Comment: As in Collection.isEmpty() ? My payload is not a collection so there will be no method isEmpty(). Do you have the same issue with == null then? I can get around the issue by using instanceof. The main issue is that I should be able to use == null

Answer (score 1):

This works on version 3.5: `#[payload is NullPayload]`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be still true in the very lastest version of Mule as per this [code](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.x/core/src/test/java/org/mule/el/context/MessageContextTestCase.java#L154).

This won't work if you are at a version < than 3.4

Comment: I'm using 3.5.1. #[payload == null] fails if the payload is NullPayload

Answer (score 0):

This is quite interesting.

The expression which is not working for you is working for me:

```
<when expression="#[!(payload == null)]">
```

and interestingly the other suggestions (listed below) are not giving the expected results:

```
<when expression="!(payload instanceof org.mule.transport.NullPayload)">
<when expression="#[!(payload is org.mule.transport.NullPayload)]">
<when expression="#[!(payload is NullPayload)]">
```